# How do we know that two events are independent in a v-structure?

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

[image]

Given this Bayes net, how do I show that R and F are independent? Every "proof" I have attempted seems to involve the assumption that P(F) and P(R) are already independent.

Comment: The information in that diagram does not say $R$ and $F$ are independent.  Nor does it say $C$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $S$. These could be assumptions.

Comment: @Henry I've seen a few examples like this online (https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/hqpbdfmjns93u9/hsrvtwew4xv5x1 page 7 of the pdf), and all of them state that it is given that R and F are independent. I can't figure out how we know this though.

Comment: The convention seems to be that if there is no path in the diagram from one event to another then they are either independent (like $R$ and $F$) or conditionally independent (like $C$ and $B$ given $S$ since there are paths from $S$ to both).  I would call that an (implicit) assumption rather than a statement